# H-bridge PCB with N-channel MOSFETs and a MOSFET driver not working

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, short-circuit, wireless-charging

I recently designed an H-bridge circuit to try to develop a wireless charging circuit. I am currently generating the PWN signals with a function generator.

There are two signals which are at 10 Vp-p at 100 kHz with a 50% duty cycle. These signals are driving two MOSFET drivers ([IRS2005SPBF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2005S-DataSheet-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015364c4246229e1)). These drivers are connected to 2 N-channel MOSFETs ([IPB049N08N5](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPB049N08N5-DS-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624a75e5f1014acef620b91b56)). The subsequent circuit is made up of an LC circuit which provides the resonance for the coil.

The issue: The circuit was not working, and the power supply indicated that there was a large amount of current flowing which might indicate a short circuit somewhere. I removed two MOSFETs and then the circuit worked.

Both drivers would only output the LO signal. Adding a 10 kΩ gate resistor to the circuit subsequently solved that issue (this is still with the 2 MOSFETs removed).

I currently can see the output of the MOSFET drivers at the input to the MOSFETs. When I soldered the 2 MOSFETs back to the circuit, I had the same issue I had at the beginning. I am not exactly sure where I went wrong. My schematic is based on the [200 W development kit from Würth](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/electronic_components/produkte_pb/demoboards/wireless_power/design_kit_200_w/wireless_power_200wkit_page.php).

The circuit also has a 24 V to 12 V voltage regulator, and a TL494 PWM generator which has been removed for the sake of testing. The two blue wires connected to the MOSFET drivers are from the function generator and hence soldered to the input wires of the MOSFET drivers.

[image]

[image]

The schematic is of the gate driver circuit, and the PCB with the added resistor soldered directly to the board.

Edit1:
[image]
This is the input waveform that is being given to the two mosfet drivers as a HIN and LIN

[image]
The output waveform at mosfet driver U4, the driver on the right.

[image]
The output waveform of the mosfet driver u3, the driver on the left. For some reason Q3 or the top left mosfet doesnt seem to show any switching now. hence the constant voltage ~12v.

Edit 2:
[image]
This is the HIN and LIN input zoomed in. 48% duty cycle, reduced the frequency to 50kHz But as pointed out, this does not have a dead time.

[image]
This is the VB VS output waveforms. VB-> Yellow, Vs-> Green

[image]
This is the VB and VS output waveforms. VB-> Yellow, Vs-> Green

Edit 3:
I changed the Mosfet driver from IRS2005 to the IRS2108.
[image]

This is the measurement taken at the outputs of the mosfet driver U4(to the right of the schematic). There seems to be small amount of dead time there added from the mosfet driver.

[image]

This is the output from the mosfet driver u3.(To the left. The mosfet Q3 or the one connected to the 24V supply is stuck high. while the 2nd mosfet Q5 has the switching input from the mosfet driver)

Still Not sure why the mosfet is stuck high. is it due to the Rgs resistor or need for a bigger boot capacitor?

Comment: What Vboot voltage do you measure with regards to Vs? Is your bootstrap diode fast enough and can take the voltage? Is your bootstrap capacitor large enough? How does startup of the circuit look? Do you have any soft start ramp? Do you have any deadtime between HIN and LIN? If not (a true 50/50), you will have shoot through current. Please post oscillograms.

Comment: The Voltage at Vs for mosfet driver U4 is ~12V while the voltage at U3 is 0V. i changed the capacitor value from 100nF to 330nF. I currently do not have a dead time with this input from the function generator. but changed the duty to 48%, but i guess thats not the same.

Comment: No, it's not the same @EmeraldMonk

Comment: Please zoom in (in time) on the crossing between HIN and LIN.

Comment: Please measure Vboot, HO and Vs in an oscillogram.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't tell the DC levels of each. I'm not used to Aglient though. As pointed out, you need to add a deadband between HO and LO of about 100 ns or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Shoot-through" is a name given to the simultaneous or over-lapping conduction of both MOSFETs in a half-bridge circuit. To avoid this we leave several tens of nanoseconds gap between deactivating the lower MOSFET and activating the upper MOSFET then, perform the same ritual when deactivating the upper MOSFET and re-activating the lower MOSFET for each half-bridge.

Of course, this is made easy by buying/using MOSFET drivers that have anti-shoot-through circuits built in like this: -

[image]

However, your MOSFET drivers don't have anti-shoot-through avoidance circuits and, you appear to be driving both MOSFETS without any care in this respect. This will produce large surge currents in your power supply.

Image taken from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/503865/how-is-dead-time-in-a-half-bridge-implemented/503871#503871) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621670/remove-half-bridge-current-spikes/621673#621673).

Comment: This makes total sense. I have another mosfet driver kicking around -> [IRS2108SPBF ](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irs2108.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567649d627a8) this has cross conduction prevention logic. would help with the anti-shoot through circuit?

Comment: I expect it will help greatly @EmeraldMonk

Comment: What would you recommend to be an appropriate dead time for the respective PWM waves. 50ns?

Comment: Try it and see what happens. It's hard to make recommendations without simulating but, 50 ns sounds about the right ballpark @EmeraldMonk

Comment: i made the change of the mosfet driver. This is probably the first time the PCB "Turns On" with all 4 MOSFETS soldered to the PCB. So im guessing that a change of the mosfet driver was a must. But im still confused as to why the single mosfet is stuck high? would that be due to the large dead time from the mosfet driver? its roughly 400ns.

Comment: That may be because the top MOSFET died and went short circuit when you didn't have dead time; the current flow could be easily 50 amps for a short period and damage it.

Comment: I changed out the MOSFET to a new one, but i am still getting the same Problem. The gate is being supplied with 20V, I think there is a short somewhere because i get ~19V at the source. and further get ~19V at the Vs pin, hence not allowing the Mosfet to switch. But im not understanding why.

Comment: Other than the driver chip, I don't see anything wrong with your circuit. Maybe try without the coil and maybe just concentrate on one half of the H bridge at a time to see what the output waveforms look like @EmeraldMonk

Comment: @EmeraldMonk 20 V Vgs is very high. Can it withstand it?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Thats why I'm a bit stumped,. The circuit works as expected on the right hand side. but the top left mosfet just doesn't want to work. ive changed it twice now. Not exactly sure where I've messed up.

Comment: @Andyaka, Im testing currently without the Coil. Ill disconnect/remove one half, and try to get it to work.

Comment: Each half works when the other half isn't connected. But when both sides are present, the power supply cuts off, which means there is a short circuit/large current draw somewhere. I have no idea what is happening. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: At perfect resonance the series L and C act like a short circuit so, maybe you need to control the duty cycle of your input PWM so that it is much smaller @EmeraldMonk <-- you could achieve the same by lowering the 24 volt DC supply to something much lower then building it up gradually to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the Help, I found out that the footprint of the MOSFET was wrong. By this i mean that the Source and the drain were interchanged. This caused the wrong signals//voltages being inputted to the wrong pins hence causing the short circuit. I would like to point out the advice from @Andy aka, and @winny helped me to understand the circuit more and prompted me to change the MOSFET driver which also the wrong one chosen by me. Changing it to the new MOSFET Driver and making the changes to the PCB has made the circuit work enough for me to continue with further tests.